# concatenation of date and time and format it

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a below data set.

```
Create table #table
(
    id int,
    filedate int,
    filedate_time datetime2
)

Insert into #table
select 1,20190801,'8/1/2019 1:33:25 PM'
union
select 2,20190802,'8/2/2019 2:40:25 PM'
union
select 3,20190803,'8/3/2019 1:33:25 PM'

select 
    cast(filedate_time as time) as time_only,
    cast(filedate as varchar(8)) as filedate,
    concat(cast(filedate as varchar(8)), ' ', cast(filedate_time as time)) as concatfield
from 
    #table
```

I would like to concatenate time from filedate_time and date from filedate and format them in yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss.fff.

I cannot use FORMAT function as it says first argument shouldn't be varchar. I am not able to convert concat field into datetime2. it gives me error saying cannot convert string to datetime. I cannot change the source data types.

Can anyone please help me to get the right format?

I want concatfield to be  "20190805-3:50:55 PM"

Comment: formatting should really be left to the presentation layer.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your sample as you have filedate column as an int so you could not store the string i.e. '20190801' in there?  Is it a char, varchar, date, datetime or datetime2?

Answer (score 0):

As @Larnu said you "should leave formatting to the presentation layer" and leave basic data in the database. However if you REALLY have to do this for some reason try:

```
select CONCAT(cast(filedate as varchar(8)), '-', FORMAT(filedate_time,'hh:mm tt'))
from #table
```